# Facebook basic page information (name) not being saved

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When trying to edit the basic information for the display name of page (not the vanity url) the information does not get saved.

I am trying to change the name from "FirstName LastName" to "fila"

On save, the page results in a blank page and the information isn't saved.

[image: Blank page response]

Web Inspector shows that the name field is sent in the form data,

```
Form data
profile_super_category:1013  
...  
pageid:name:fila  
...
```

but nothing in my eyes comes out as any error message or the response.

The page is unpublished.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is there any error message? What happens when you try to save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched various sites for information to resolve this and most seem to point to clearing the IP access activity in security settings. Clearing out all devices and activity stil resulted in no changes in the page.

I ended up adding one extra character to the name "afila" and after that the changes were saved.

It seems Facebook applies the *5 letter username rule* to display names although it is implicitly implied by the silent fail with the blank page.

So in order to change the display name of the page, the display name *must be at least 5 characters*. I was able to successfully change other items on the page after doing this.

Comment: Maybe is also the fact that Facebook requires only real names and somehow it detects that you are trying to change it to something else.

Comment: @Alex it could be though business pages can have non-personal names such as Nike, Adidas ..etc.